# How to create a FileFolder in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts

Windows has the ability to create shortcuts. When you do, they appear as shortcuts in the files section of a folder. To create one, you right click, new, shortcut, or copy and paste as shortcut amonst other options.

However, windows also has something called a FileFolder, which is a shortcut that is treated like a folder, rather than a file. So with sorting, it appears in the folders location, it appears in the folderviewpane and from the addressbar.

Now, there's also the symbolic links, which is similar to FileFolders, but one thing a symbolic link cannot do, is be placed on a network share and point to a folder on your local computer that is not shared, and if you open that link from a different computer, it opens on their computer instead, like a normal shortcut would do.

A way to create a FileFolder is to use the *Add a network location* wizard and link to it.

So far I figured out that the location of this FileFolder is:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
```

Opening this folder in command prompt allows me to debug how this folder is made.

It is a regular folder, not a file. Performing an attrib shows me this:

```
C:\....\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts>attrib /d /s
   SH        C:\....\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\test\desktop.ini
A            C:\....\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\test\target.lnk
     R       C:\....\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\test
```

So a Folder without archive or system attribute set, but with read only, which contains a normal target.lnk (the shortcut to where it points) and a desktop.ini with system and hidden attribute set but not archive, to glue it all together.

The content of desktop.ini shows me:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
Flags=2
```

I can rename the desktop.ini to desktop.ini~ and then navigate the folder with explorer. Deleting the target.lnk file and right-click new->shortcut and point it to something, then name it target and renaming desktop.ini~ back to desktop.ini succesfully alters the target, and I can succesfully copy/move the new FileFolder.

## The question

Now the thing is, I can succesfully modify a filefolder that works, but I can't seem to figure out how to manually create one from scratch. Eg: Right mouse->New folder, Give attributes, Inside create the appropriate files.

I go to the previous folder and back in, and I just see the desktop.ini and target.lnk instead of getting redirected.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work, or what steps I need to take to make it work?

Comment: @Ramhound I couldn't get it to work, and I know the startmenu has gone through a big overhaul in these windows versions. But maybe I'm doing something wrong. Anyway, it would still be a workaround. I prefer to find out how to do it myself. I can now just create a FileFolder once, store it somewhere, and copy/paste it then modify when needing it, but for the sake of learning, it should be possible to create one manually, so I'd like to figure out how.

Comment: @Ramhound but I get your drift. Edited out the Windows 8 and above part.

Comment: I will be honest, I have not heard of FileFolders before, so I will have to do my research.  The statement raised my eyebrows though.

Comment: @Ramhound regarding the startmenu way, seemed to be XP sp1 and earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why things aren't working. All steps I did were correct except for one: Giving my folder a +r attribute.

Using explorer to set the read-only attribute is not working on folders it seems.

But when using attrib Filefolder +r suddenly explorer started to understand, and things work.

So the easiest way now is to first create the folder and attrib it, then create the appropriate files inside.

So:

```
C:\>md FileFolder

C:\>attrib FileFolder +r

C:\>cd FileFolder

C:\FileFolder>start .
```

Now from the explorer window, create a desktop.ini with the following content:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
Flags=2
```

Make sure the desktop.ini has an enter after the Flags=2, otherwise its still not working.

And right-click `New` > `Shortcut`, point it to where it has to go, and name it `target`

Now, Go up a directory, and you'll notice the icon has a shortcut arrow on it, yet it is a folder. Clicking on it will properly redirect.

Note: It may take up to a minute for the shortcut to start working.

EDIT: Additionally, providing your shortcut with a different icon will allow that icon to be shown in your shortcutfolder too.

Comment: Hmm. "using attrib Filefolder +r suddenly explorer started to understand" in the text but `attrib FileFolder +h` in the code? which is correct? Hidden or Read-Only?

Comment: @DavidPostill oh, good spot. its +r of course.