# Compress symbolic links on Windows 10

Tags: windows, compression, symbolic-link

Using Windows 10. I have a directory with some symbolic links (or "soft links" or symlinks, if you prefer). The symlinked files/folders were created using

```
mklink [/d]
```

commands. I want to compress them. Using 7zip, windows builtin zip and MINGSW32 tar, all transform the symlinks to regular files/folders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you replace the symlink with a filefolder, it will be possible to compress them. See: http://superuser.com/questions/1114114/how-to-create-a-filefolder-in-windows

Comment: Nice workaround, may come handy! Didn't know about FileFolders.

Comment: There's only one small thing to note: It does not work on a NAS because the linux filesystem does not allow you to make a folder read-only by using attrib +r.